# Informatica. How to reject whole source file if source and target have duplicates

Tags: oracle, plsql, mapping, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a mapping which compares target with source. In expression there is a condition which checks if there are duplicates. How can I stop whole data flow if condition returns true? DD_Reject does not work as it only rejects one record.

Comment: Does this help? https://network.informatica.com/thread/6853

Comment: do you want to stop the whole flow if source has duplicates ? Or you want to reject duplicated data and process rest? or you dont want to process any data if it exists in both source and target

Answer (score 0):

To stop the flow use the available `Expression Transformation` [ABORT](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/transformation-language-reference/functions/abort.html) function. This will NOT rollback the already process rows though. If you need that as well, then two sessions will be needed, one to check the duplicates, another to perform the actual load, linked with `SUCCEEDED` condition.

```
Start -> s_check_duplicates -succeeded-> s_load_data
```